# How can I convert a list full of hexadecimal integers into a new file?

Tags: python, file, hex

What I mean by this is that how can I take a list of hexadecimal values like this: ['0x1', '0x2', '0x1e4b1', '0x5b', '0x80', '0x52', '0x111', '0x6b0d', '0x4e', '0x34a', '0x2067', '0x6ef3', '0x1cf', '0x1b', '0x15b', '0x4f', '0xba8', '0x319'] and put them all into a new file called hexadecimal values?

Here is some background information to help:
I have a .txt file with some numbers on it that are all separated by commas. Then, using Python code, I opened it and read it. After that, I made a list out of all of the numbers that were on the file. When I made a list, the numbers were all strings (example: '9', '8', etc.), so I used some Python code to convert the values of the list into integers. After doing that, I converted all of the integers into a hexadecimal form. Now, what I am trying to do is convert the list of hexadecimal integers into a new .txt file. I have tried to research a lot about this, so please help.

Here is my code so far for what I have done to reach this point:

```
my_file = open(r'C:\Users\KAPS\Downloads\List of Numbers File.txt', 
encoding='utf-8-sig')

content = my_file.read()

print(content)

content_list = content.split(",")

my_file.close()

print(content_list)

for i in range(0, len(content_list)):
    content_list[i] = int(content_list[i])

print(str(content_list))

hex_list = [hex(int(x)) for x in content_list]
print(hex_list)
```

Here is what I want my result to look like at the very end:

Because I do not have enough reputation, the link to the image is below. Please click on that. The only difference between my result and this picture here is that I want my result at the end to open a *new* .txt file named Hexadecimal Values and not the OG one called List of Numbers.

Link to Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZKQk.jpg

Comment: Do you want to write the hex values as strings into the file or the integer values?

Comment: I am trying to get them to be integer values separated by commas if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the hexadecimal strings in the file, you could do the following:

```
hex_list = ['0x1', '0x2', '0x1e4b1', '0x5b', '0x80', '0x52', '0x111', '0x6b0d', '0x4e', '0x34a', '0x2067', '0x6ef3', '0x1cf', '0x1b']
with open(r'C:\Users\KAPS\Downloads\output_numbers.txt', 'w') as my_file:
    my_file.write(', '.join(hex_list))
```

The code does the following:

1. Open a new file with the name "output_numbers" in write mode - the keywords 'with.. as' are used to automatically close the file after writing (it's called a context manager).
2. Writing the elements of the list hex_list into the file as comma separated values. This is done by using the string operation [join](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). As a list is an iterable and the list consists only of string elements, this works.

Comment: But what if I want to keep the hexadecimal values as integers and make a new file where I can put all these hexadecimal values? Could you help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: I don't get what you want to have written to the result file. Please show a result file snippet example.

Comment: What I want to do is take the list of hexadecimal values and then open a new file where I could put all the hexadecimal values in. Is this easier to understand? I will edit my question to show what I want the result to be like.

Comment: I have adapted my post, if it isn't clear now please let me know.

Comment: If possible, can you explain exactly what your code does because when I put the exact code you wrote in my code block, nothing really happens?

Comment: There should be a file `output_numbers.txt`in your Downloads directory. I have extended my answer to explain the code.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! This was really helpful. I will make sure to try it out and see if it works and tell you.

Comment: It worked. I really appreciate your help. Thank you!